How to automatically login to a website using firebase authentication without using browser automation tools?
I have this web i want to scrape daily, by sending different http requests with bearer token to the site. The task requires me to manually log in with my google account, copy the bearer token and send request using scrapy. How to automate that process without using any browser automation tools like selenium, playwright...
The end goal is to send http requests and get data automatically.
I tried to use google cloud console to get my google account id token, use it to exchange the firebase token. I got a message that google id token is not allowed to be used with that application. Its audience (OAuth 2.0 client ID) is not authorized to be used in the project.

Create a project in the Google Cloud Console.
Enable the Google Identity API and Firebase Authentication API.
Create OAuth 2.0 credentials, and get the client ID and client secret.
Use the OAuth 2.0 flow to get an authentication token for your Google Account.
Store the refresh token to automatically renew the token.
Use the Firebase Authentication API to replace the Google OAuth token with a Firebase ID token.
Use the Firebase ID to authenticate HTTP requests.
Here is the JavaScript code in Google Apps Script:
